# Что мне сделать, чтобы ты на меня не сердилась?

Tags: синтаксис

Помогите, пожалуйста, не могу понять: это изъяснительное придаточное с целевым оттенком или придаточное цели?

*Что мне сделать, **чтобы ты на меня не сердилась**?*

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) **Что мне сделать, чтобы ты на меня не сердилась?**

Обычное придаточное цели, **присоставная** связь, то есть союз ЧТОБЫ соединяет главное и придаточное предложения. (Вопрос "что делать, что сделать" – это общий вопрос для всех глаголов).

2) Ближайший по теме вариант изъяснительного типа: **Все мои усилия направлены на то, чтобы ты на меня не сердилась.** Это приместоименное изъяснительное предложение  **вмещающего типа** (особый вид): опорное слово   со значением (в данном случае) **деятельности, занятий, усилий + указательное слово**, содержание которого раскрывается в придаточном предложении (**присловная** связь).

3) **Справочный материал** (как определить СПП с придаточным изъяснительным обычного типа)

Придаточные изъяснительные относятся **к опорному слову** в предложении – глаголу, существительному или наречию, значение которого **связано с передачей мыслей, чувств и т.д.**

**Опорные слова делятся на следующие группы:**

А) Со значением речи: сказать, объяснить, попросить,  скрыть; известие, сообщение, рассказ, история.

Б) Со значение мысли: думать, знать, подозревать; мысль (о том), догадка, вера, мнение; известно, понятно, странно, очевидно.

В) Со значением  желания, воли, усилий: желать, хотеть, надеяться, стараться; желание, решение.

Г) Со значением восприятия или ощущения: видеть, слышать, казаться, чувствовать, следить; чувство, предчувствие; видно, заметно.

Д) Со значением эмоционального состояния: радоваться, бояться, жалеть; неприятно, жаль.

Е) Со значением оценки и характеристики: плохо, хорошо, важно, не беда, главное.

Ж) С модальным значением: нельзя, нужно, необходимо, возможно, желательно.

З) С бытийным значением: бывает, оказалось, выходит, случается.

**Используемые союзы имеют следующие характеристики:**
союз ЧТО – нейтральный;

союз КАК – достоверный (значение восприятия, ощущения);

союз БУДТО  – вероятностный /недостоверный (делает вид, будто бы…);

союз ЧТОБЫ – ирреальная модальность (побуждение, приказ, запрет, необходимость, возможность, желание, целенаправленное наблюдение (следить, чтобы…), также при отрицании (не пом**ню, чтобы…), также опасение (боюсь, как бы…);

частица ЛИ – для передачи вопросительной речи.

**Пример:** Левинсон **распорядился** (= сказал), **чтобы** (= приказ) к вечеру собрался для обсуждения Морозкиного поступка сельский сход вместе с отрядом.

Comment: WOW!!!!!!! большое спасибо!!!

Comment: не могли бы Вы пожалуйста просмотреть следующие примеры. По-моему, они похожи на Ваши (с опорным словом "том" и "нужно"), я хотела бы удостовериться, что правильно определила их (как изъяснительные придаточные): (1) Система воспитания построена на том, чтобы развивались интересы ребенка.  
(2) Нужно зажмурить глаза, чтобы сузились зрачки. (надо задавать вопрос "для чего?" или "с какой целью?")

Comment: Пример (1) - это изъяснительное придаточное "вмещающего типа", опорное слово со значением характеристики/оценки, указательное слово обязательно (его содержание раскрывает придаточное).  (Вообще говоря, эти СПП близки по значению к местоименно-определительным СПП).  Пример (2)  - обычное обстоятельственное придаточное цели (действие - цель действия), в нем не выделяется  изъяснительная часть. Сравнить Нужно (что?), чтобы зрачки были суженными (вот это уже изъяснительное СПП).

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, придаточное цели.

А какой вопрос Вы зададите к изъяснительному? Если бы было в главном указательное слово ТАКОЕ,было бы определительное со значением цели. По смыслу на него похоже,но ведь его нет, значит, цели.

Comment: Большое спасибо, Людмила!!! Не могли бы Вы дать совет как мне научиться отличать изъяснительные придаточные с целевым оттенком от целевых? 
Нашла линк: http://www.studfiles.ru/preview/1101556/page:16/ 
Там пример: Левинсон распорядился, чтобы к вечеру со­брался для обсуждения Морозкиного поступка сельский сход вместе с отря­дом.
Мне тяжело понять, почему это изъяснительное предложение, если задаю вопрос "с какой целью распорядился Левинсон?"

Comment: Распорядился не с какой целью?, а о чём?